# UML: Analysis-level class diagram. Should the detail entity be represented in this diagram

Tags: uml, analysis, class-diagram, rup

I'm learning UML and have this scenario. This is a screen to assign players to a game room. The admnistrator selects the Game from the drop down, then selects the Game Room, and finally moves the players from the list on the left to the right list to indicate what players are assigned to the selected room. The question is if the detail entity should be represented as an entity in the Analysis-level class diagram. See below GUI and the 2 options I have for the diagram. Which one is correct #1 or #2?

**GUI**

[image]

**Diagram 1: Should "AssignedPlayers" be include in this diagram as an entity class?**

[image]

**Diagram 2: Should I exclude the entity AssignedPlayers and leave only Player and GameRoom classes and later, in the Conceptual Model, relate the GameRoom and Player entities with an Association Class called AssignedPlayers?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to decide. Both are correct. You create a diagram to communicate a model to some audience. If that audience is not interested in certain detail you just leave it away (if that does not totally distort the picture).

You create not a single diagram for a system but as many as needed. So for an overview you have diagrams with few/no details and many other diagrams that go in certain details.

Remember: UML is about communication, not about diagramming.